# C++ (Eigen) - Coefficientwise boolean between two differently sized vector

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Suppose I have two Eigen Arrays defined as

```
Array<float, 10, 1> a;
Array<float, 4, 1> b;
```

Now, I would like to get an Array of `Array<bool, 10, 4> result;` reading `true` for every one of the 10 entries of `a` where it is larger than every of the four entries of `b`. One way to achieve that I thought of was:

```
Array<float, 10, 1> a; 
Array<float, 4, 1> b;
// ... fill the arrays
Array<bool, 10, 4> result = a.replicate(1 , 4) > (b.transpose()).replicate(10, 1);
```

In reality, the matrix dimensions are much larger though. This approach works, but I have two questions.

First: if I replace `Array<bool, 10, 4> result = ...` by `auto result = ...`,using the `result` is much slower for some reason (I use it after to do some calculations based on the outcome of the bool).

Second: While this works, I wonder if this is the most efficient approach as I don't know whether replicate requires copying. I could consider iterating over one of the two dimensions

```
Array<float, 10, 1> a; 
Array<float, 4, 1> b;
// ... fill the arrays
Array<bool, 10, 4> result;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    result.col(i) = a > b(i, 0);
}
```

which would remove the necessity of using `replicate` at the cost of adding an iteration.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's the chunk of code of interest. It gets called very often and so speedup is of great concern. Right now, this eats up 90% of the overall execution time. It is part of line intersection detection for thousands of lines. My approach was to write all the checks in matrix expressions to avoid iterating over all line pairs. To do that, I build a matrix with `n` rows for all `n` lines and `m` columns for all lines the other `n` lines could collide with. Then, the line intersection formula can be applied coefficientwise over the big matrices which I hope brings speedup.

```
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x1 = rays.col(0).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x2 = (rays.col(2) + rays.col(0)).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y1 = rays.col(1).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y2 = (rays.col(3) + rays.col(1)).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());

    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x3 = obstacles.col(0).transpose().replicate(num_rays*num_ships, 1);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x4 = obstacles.col(2).transpose().replicate(num_rays*num_ships, 1);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y3 = obstacles.col(1).transpose().replicate(num_rays*num_ships, 1);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y4 = obstacles.col(3).transpose().replicate(num_rays*num_ships, 1);

    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> t_den = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4) -(y1-y2)*(x3-x4);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> t = (x1-x3)*(y3-y4) -(y1-y3)*(x3-x4)/t_den;
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> u = ((x1-x3)*(y1-y2) - (y1-y3)*(x1-x2));
    Eigen::Array<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> col_r = 0 <= t && 0 <= u && u <= t_den;
    t_rays = col_r.select(t, 1000).rowwise().minCoeff();


    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x1_ = ship_b_boxs.col(0).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x2_ = (ship_b_boxs.col(2)).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y1_ = ship_b_boxs.col(1).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y2_ = (ship_b_boxs.col(3)).replicate(1, 4*obs.size());

    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x3_ = x3(Eigen::seq(0, 4*num_ships-1), Eigen::all);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> x4_ = x4(Eigen::seq(0, 4*num_ships-1), Eigen::all);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y3_ = y3(Eigen::seq(0, 4*num_ships-1), Eigen::all);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> y4_ = y4(Eigen::seq(0, 4*num_ships-1), Eigen::all);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> t_den_ = (x1_-x2_)*(y3_-y4_) -(y1_-y2_)*(x3_-x4_);
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> t_ = (x1_-x3_)*(y3_-y4_) -(y1_-y3_)*(x3_-x4_)/t_den_;
    Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> u_ = ((x1_-x3_)*(y1_-y2_) - (y1_-y3_)*(x1_-x2_));
    Eigen::Array<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> col_s = (0 <= t_ && t_ <= 1 && 0 <= u_ &&  u_ <= t_den_).rowwise().maxCoeff();
```

with 85% taken by `inlined'Eigen::Array::Array'`. I can see that probably now all the temporary array constructions take a lot of time. However, storing these temporary variables is beneficial as they are used more than once. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Regarding the ```auto```: Note this in the documentation https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html Basically you are keeping an expression around (not the final array) and it seems like in the further processing you do, you repeatedly evaluate it. That is why it is slower.

Comment: As for the replication, I think the ```colwise()``` and ```rowwise()``` operations are intended to solve this but I'm having a hard time wrangling them into what you need. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html

Comment: Thanks homer. I've looked into the colwise and rowwise operations too but haven't quite figured how to use them here.

Answer (score 3):

> First: if I replace Array<bool, 10, 4> result = ... by auto result =
> ...,using the result is much slower for some reason (I use it after to
> do some calculations based on the outcome of the bool).

As mentioned by @Homer512 in a comment, [do not use auto in Eigen expressions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html)

> Second: While this works, I wonder if this is the most efficient
> approach as I don't know whether replicate requires copying

No, if you use `replicate` within an expression and you do not *actively* store it in some intermediate variable or otherwise force the expression to be evaluated, there is no copying involved. As in typical Eigen style `replicate` only returns *an expression of the replication*, see [the doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html), an actual object containing a full replica is only created if *absolutely* necessary.

In short, *this* involves copies:

```cpp
Array<bool, 10, 4> a4r = a.replicate(1 , 4);
Array<bool, 10, 4> b4r = b.transpose().replicate(10, 1);
Array<bool, 10, 4> result = a4r > b4r;
```

while your expression does not:

```cpp
Array<bool, 10, 4> result = a.replicate(1 , 4) > b.transpose().replicate(10, 1);
```

So I really think it's the most efficient way to do it, or close to it.

How is this magic possible? It is well explained in [the doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html).

---

Side note:

- if your matrices are big you should consider switching to dynamic size, see [Eigen's own recommendations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) "Fixed vs. Dynamic size"
- on the other hand, if you do know the sizes at compile time, you could consider the templeate version of replicate: `a.replicate<1,4>() > b.transpose().replicate<10,1>();`

---

If you still do not believe there is no copying involved, you can check the source code, as of version 3.4.0

`Eigen/src/Core/Replicate.h`

```cpp
template<typename MatrixType,int RowFactor,int ColFactor> class Replicate
  : public internal::dense_xpr_base< Replicate<MatrixType,RowFactor,ColFactor> >::type
{
    [...]

    template<typename OriginalMatrixType>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    inline Replicate(const OriginalMatrixType& matrix, Index rowFactor, Index colFactor)
      : m_matrix(matrix), m_rowFactor(rowFactor), m_colFactor(colFactor)
    {
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((internal::is_same<typename internal::remove_const<MatrixType>::type,OriginalMatrixType>::value),
                          THE_MATRIX_OR_EXPRESSION_THAT_YOU_PASSED_DOES_NOT_HAVE_THE_EXPECTED_TYPE)
    }

    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_CONSTEXPR
    inline Index rows() const { return m_matrix.rows() * m_rowFactor.value(); }
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_CONSTEXPR
    inline Index cols() const { return m_matrix.cols() * m_colFactor.value(); }

    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    const _MatrixTypeNested& nestedExpression() const
    {
      return m_matrix;
    }

  protected:
    MatrixTypeNested m_matrix;
    const internal::variable_if_dynamic<Index, RowFactor> m_rowFactor;
    const internal::variable_if_dynamic<Index, ColFactor> m_colFactor;
};
```

`Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h`

```cpp
    const Replicate<Derived, Dynamic, Dynamic> replicate(Index rowFactor, Index colFactor) const
    {
      return Replicate<Derived, Dynamic, Dynamic>(derived(), rowFactor, colFactor);
    }
```

`Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h`

```cpp
template<typename ArgType, int RowFactor, int ColFactor>
struct unary_evaluator<Replicate<ArgType, RowFactor, ColFactor> >
  : evaluator_base<Replicate<ArgType, RowFactor, ColFactor> >
{
  [...]

  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
  explicit unary_evaluator(const XprType& replicate)
    : m_arg(replicate.nestedExpression()),
      m_argImpl(m_arg),
      m_rows(replicate.nestedExpression().rows()),
      m_cols(replicate.nestedExpression().cols())
  {}

  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
  CoeffReturnType coeff(Index row, Index col) const
  {
    // try to avoid using modulo; this is a pure optimization strategy
    const Index actual_row = internal::traits<XprType>::RowsAtCompileTime==1 ? 0
                           : RowFactor==1 ? row
                           : row % m_rows.value();
    const Index actual_col = internal::traits<XprType>::ColsAtCompileTime==1 ? 0
                           : ColFactor==1 ? col
                           : col % m_cols.value();

    return m_argImpl.coeff(actual_row, actual_col);
  }

  [...]

protected:
  const ArgTypeNested m_arg;
  evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned> m_argImpl;
  const variable_if_dynamic<Index, ArgType::RowsAtCompileTime> m_rows;
  const variable_if_dynamic<Index, ArgType::ColsAtCompileTime> m_cols;
};
```

I know that the code is heavy and difficult to interpret if you are not familiar with this kind of mechanisms, that's why I've removed all but the most relevant part. What you need to retain is this: `replicate` only creates an expression of type `Replicate` which simply stores a reference to the original object, the number of row copies, and the number of column copies; then, when you want to retrieve a coefficient from the expression, the evaluator computes the appropriate index in the *original* matrix using modulo and returns the corresponding element.

Comment: Thank for for this extensive answer. If I understand correctly, I should avoid explicitly storing the replicate result in a new expression to avoid copies. However, consider I have the same example but now I have two expressions: `Array<bool, 10, 4> result1 =  a.replicate(1 , 4) > b.transpose().replicate(10, 1);` and `Array<bool, 10, 4> result2 = a.replicate(1, 4) < 200*b.transpose().replicate(10, 1);`
Now, to avoid copying, I use replicate without explicitly storing the result in an intermediate variable. But then, I call replicate twice on `a` and `b`. Is it still better than copying?

Comment: I've added my original post to include the actual code, that should include some insight.

Comment: I think it's still better, `replicate` itself does really have a runtime cost, it's all about how to access the original matrix... The _only_ performance penalty I can think of is that `Replicate`'s evaluator employs the modulo function to compute the correct address, as duly noted in a comment to the code itself

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure about it, in terms of time performance is it better to store a copy somewhere or use modulo for every access? Not sure...

Comment: Okay. Maybe to generalize the question: Considering my goal, which is to determine mutual intersection between two groups of lines (which line of group a intersect which line of group b?), is the matrix approach I have here an efficient way to go about it?

Comment: Mmmh, don't know, that sounds like another question :) Anyhow, for a quick test, in your newly-posted code, have you tried using `auto` for `x1` `x2` `x3` `x4` `y1` `y2` `y3` `y4` ? _Not_ for `t_den`, `t` and `u` though, you said yourself that `Array<bool, 10, 4> result` by `auto result` is slower. That would be equivalent to replacing the subexpressions. I know I've just written that "do not use auto", but there's always exceptions to the rule, after all it's only "unless you are 100% sure about what you are doing" ;)